# How to separating frontend and backend using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am a new php developer. Am developing my website using codeigniter and got stuck when i tried to make the backend. Am using CMS backend that comes with its own folder with everything (.htaccess, its own MVC etc) so I put all my frontend folders into one folder called frontend withinn the application folder but now I cannt view my frontend pages. I get this: The configuration file does not exist. Please help me step by step.

Comment: This is a question begging a big answer. Please check the CodeIgniter examples and documentation.

Comment: Your best bet in that case would be to rewrite the CMS into CI, having separate controllers and views. Probably even models.

Answer (score 0):

check out this link to know the MVC pattern [Codeigniter](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/).

controller and model ----- Backend

Views --- Frontend